# kestrel serve static file starting with a dot

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

`kestrel` (`net5.0-windows`) is configured to serve static files and allow directory browsing for a non-bare git repository:

```
services.AddDirectoryBrowser();

var requestPath = "";
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"D:\MyGitRepo");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { FileProvider = fileProvider, RequestPath = requestPath, ServeUnknownFileTypes = true, });
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions { FileProvider = fileProvider, RequestPath = requestPath });

.UseWebRoot(@"D:\MyGitRepo")
.UseContentRoot(@"D:\MyGitRepo")
```

the directory browser does not show the `.git` folder and the `.gitignore` file is not found, how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it by using `PhysicalFileProvider` constructor's second parameter:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical;
...
...
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"D:\MyGitRepo", ExclusionFilters.None);
```